# Changing a variable inside a if - jade/pugjs

Tags: pug, pugjs

I'm trying to make a div have a location inside of it based on the state of two variables, for example if `$city = 'New York'` and `$state = 'NY'` the div would display `New York, NY`. However, it's not working and I think it has to do with scoping. Here's my jade:

```
$city = data.City
$state = data.State
$locString = ""

if $city != ""
    $locString = $locString + $city
if $city != "" && $state != ""
    $locString = $locString + ", "
if $state != ""
    $locString = $locString + $state

.location #{$locString}
```

This is ending with $locString being empty, but if I print off $locString inside the if statements it has only the most recently added value, suggesting that it is redeclaring a local copy of the variable inside of each if statement. I can't find anything about this in the reference http://jade-lang.com/reference/

Answer (score 0):

I woud suggest this:

```
- var city = data.City
- var state = data.State
- var locString = ""

if city != ""
    - locString = locString + city
if city != "" && state != ""
    - locString = locString + ", "
if state != ""
    - locString = locString + state
```

Take care of the "var" and "-".

Check "Variables" part on -> https://naltatis.github.io/jade-syntax-docs/